# Working with large CSV files in Ruby

Tags: ruby, csv, data-integration

I want to parse two CSV files of the MaxMind GeoIP2 database, do some joining based on a column and merge the result into one output file.

I used standard CSV ruby library, it is very slow. I think it tries to load all the file in memory.

```
block_file = File.read(block_path)
block_csv   = CSV.parse(block_file, :headers => true) 
location_file = File.read(location_path)
location_csv = CSV.parse(location_file, :headers => true)


CSV.open(output_path, "wb",
    :write_headers=> true,
    :headers => ["geoname_id","Y","Z"] ) do |csv|


    block_csv.each do |block_row|
    puts "#{block_row['geoname_id']}"

        location_csv.each do |location_row|
            if (block_row['geoname_id'] === location_row['geoname_id'])
                puts " match :"    
                csv << [block_row['geoname_id'],block_row['Y'],block_row['Z']]
                break location_row
            end
        end

    end
```

Is there  another ruby library that support processing in chuncks ?

`block_csv` is 800MB  and  `location_csv` is 100MB.

Answer (score 6):

Just use `CSV.open(block_path, 'r', :headers => true).each do |line|` instead of `File.read` and `CSV.parse`. It will parse the file line by line.

In your current version, you explicitly tell it to read all the file with `File.read` and then to parse the whole file as a string with `CSV.parse`. So it does exactly what you have told.